# Progress bar at right side becomes empty in checkout process

Tags: magento, checkout

My requirement is to customize the Onepage checkout process and adding a new step between the “Payment Information” and “Review” Steps.

I have succefully added the tab but when I move to that tab the progress bar becomes empty.Please help me to solve this issue 
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add a steps to javascript file.
 add the below code to your phtml file `checkout.steps = ["login", "billing", "shipping", "shipping_method", "payment","exempt", "review"]`

This worked for me

Answer (score 0):

The updates for each block is up to the ajax request for each step. Check what ajax request gets fired before your step occurs and look what data is in the respond of the ajax request

Comment: Ajax shows the data but the progress bar is not updated

Comment: Can you give proper steps for this @MageZeus

Comment: Use the developer tools in your browser (F12) and choose the 'Network'-Tab, choose the XHR so only ajax request will be filtered. Then click the button in the checkout before your step occurs and check the recorded data

Comment: @Pratikbhatt  please check this link [link]http://excellencemagentoblog.com/blog/2011/10/10/magento-onestep-checkout-add-step/

I hope this will help you.